# owl-carousel add image dynamically by using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am trying add image into ".owl-carousel" by using java script.

When i try it by static , its working

```
    <div id="demo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <ul id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">


             <li class="item"><img src="puzzlepictures/img02.jpg" id="2"></li>
            <li class="item"><img src="puzzlepictures/img03.jpg" id="3"></li>
             <li class="item"><img src="puzzlepictures/img04.jpg" id="4"></li>  

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the img in li dynamic. So i tried

```
 var content = '<li class="item"><img src="'+ imageListItems.image_path; +'" ></li>';
   owl.data('owlCarousel').addItem(content);
```

when i inspect the li tag is not appending to ul.

can any one help me

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is the value of `owl`?

Comment: var owl = $("#owl-demo")    @Rejith R Krishnan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `.append()` function?
Like this;

#### JQUERY

```
var content = '<li class="item"><img src="puzzlepictures/img02.jpg" id="2"></li><li class="item"><img src="puzzlepictures/img02.jpg" id="2"></li><li class="item"><img src="puzzlepictures/img02.jpg" id="2"></li>';

var owl = $("#owl-demo");
owl.append(content);
```